# SQL to define a set of columns and then pivot the row data to them

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table of data shows the week numbers that people got a certain mark (see DDL/DML in update).

I'd like my query to define the 52 days of the week as separate columns and then list the mark for a person underneath the corresponding week number column.

The result would be something like this:

```
| PersonId | Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3 | Week 4 | Week 5 | Week 6 | Week 7 | Week 8 | etc...
|----------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------| etc...
|    1     |    P   |    P   |    P   |    P   |    P   |  Null  |  Null  |  Null  | etc...
|    2     |    P   |    X   |    X   |    P   |    P   |  Null  |  Null  |  Null  | etc...
```

I thought about trying a `PIVOT` but I don't think that will work as the row data may not necessarily have the full 52 week column headings I'm after.

I'm happy for marks under a week number column to be null if there is no mark for the week, but the query itself must show columns for weeks 1 to 52.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

**Update**: DDL and DML as requested

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
    ([Id] int, [PersonId] int, [Mark] varchar(2), [Week] int)
;

INSERT INTO mytable
    ([Id], [PersonId], [Mark], [Week])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'P', 1),
    (2, 1, 'P', 2),
    (3, 1, 'P', 3),
    (4, 1, 'P', 4),
    (5, 1, 'P', 5),
    (1, 2, 'P', 1),
    (2, 2, 'X', 2),
    (3, 2, 'X', 3),
    (4, 2, 'P', 4),
    (5, 2, 'P', 5)
;
```

Comment: Can you put out the DDL and DML statements in a pastebin or somewhere ?sqlfiddle is dead

Comment: The DDL and DML (preferably a minimal amount that still demonstrates the problem) should be part of the question, not on any external site, so that the question and answers are all fully contained here.

Comment: See updated question

Comment: Should be a simple matter of writing 52 `CASE` expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a calendar table. I usually have a physical table in most of my databases, which can contain week number (especially since some businesses might handle these slightly differently - is Wed. Jan 1st week 1 or week 52 of the previous year?), business quarter, holidays, or whatever else the specific business might need.

You can also do this with a virtual table, as seen here. Of course, you'll need to expand the weeks out to 52.

```
SELECT
    PersonID, [Week 1], [Week 2], [Week 3], [Week 4], [Week 5]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MT.PersonID, MT.Mark, CAL.WeekNumberName
        FROM
            (
                SELECT 1 AS WeekNumber, 'Week 1' AS WeekNumberName
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 2 AS WeekNumber, 'Week 2' AS WeekNumberName
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 3 AS WeekNumber, 'Week 3' AS WeekNumberName
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 4 AS WeekNumber, 'Week 4' AS WeekNumberName
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 5 AS WeekNumber, 'Week 5' AS WeekNumberName
            ) AS CAL
        LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable MT ON
            MT.Week = CAL.WeekNumber
    ) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(Mark)
        FOR WeekNumberName IN ([Week 1], [Week 2], [Week 3], [Week 4], [Week 5])
    ) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: Following select can generate 52 numbers directly. I think this way you can eliminate that UNION all section or separate calendar table. This is for oracle database, but i think you can get the idea.

    "select level-1 week_offset from dual connect by level <= 51"

Comment: The question is for SQL Server and I believe that dual is an Oracle specific construct. The UNIONs are just there to demonstrate the general idea, which is that one needs to have a resultset of the weeks to start with and then LEFT OUTER JOIN to that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of that first pesky null row when you're missing a week in `myTable` due to the left join in your pivot query you can add a where statement to the end.. Plus you dont really need to type out all of those Unions

```
WITH WeeksCTE AS 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.WeekNum) WeekNum 
    FROM (VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8)) t(WeekNum), 
         (VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8)) c(WeekNum)
)
SELECT  *
FROM (
    SELECT  CONCAT('Week ', WeekNum) WeekName,
            mt.PersonId,
            mt.Mark
    FROM    WeeksCTE cte
            LEFT JOIN mytable mt ON cte.WeekNum = mt.[Week]
) t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Mark)
    FOR WeekName IN (
        [Week 1],[Week 2],[Week 3],[Week 4],[Week 5],[Week 6],[Week 7],[Week 8],[Week 9],[Week 10],
        [Week 11],[Week 12],[Week 13],[Week 14],[Week 15],[Week 16],[Week 17],[Week 18],[Week 19],[Week 20],
        [Week 21],[Week 22],[Week 23],[Week 24],[Week 25],[Week 26],[Week 27],[Week 28],[Week 29],[Week 30],
        [Week 31],[Week 32],[Week 33],[Week 34],[Week 35],[Week 36],[Week 37],[Week 38],[Week 39],[Week 40],
        [Week 41],[Week 42],[Week 43],[Week 44],[Week 45],[Week 46],[Week 47],[Week 48],[Week 49],[Week 50],
        [Week 51],[Week 52]
    )
) p
WHERE PersonID IS NOT NULL
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b306/4)